# mysql workbench error opening EER

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, eer-model

I'm having a lubuntu-64bit and installed  MySQL-workbench to open the EER model. but it just doesn't open up..

It shows error

```
Error unserializing GRT data
error unserializing object (invalid struct)
```

The same EER file opens fine in windows.. I'm new to this I need to create Database using these on this machine please help..

Comment: same here created in xp32 now opening in xubuntu64 :(

Comment: same for windows-10 workbench-6.3

Answer (score 196):

I was facing the same issue, at last i just close the application and restarted, it resolved the issue.

Comment: Also solved a slightly different `Error unserializing GRT data
data string too long` issue (also when opening a saved MWB file)

Comment: I also encountered the same issue. I am not sure if it has to do with reinstalling my OS. Reboot solved the issue.

Comment: Just solved this by closing program and restarting :P

Comment: nice...3 years later the same error still exists (WB 8.0). But the "solution" also still works ;)

Answer (score 19):

The other solutions did not work for me, for anyone still looking for a solution I managed to open my model by closing the workbench and double clicking the actual .MWB file in the file explorer.

I hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

For me, was by **closing other tabs** (maybe the tabs that related to eer digram)

Answer (score 0):

Issue is still present in 8.0.17

I had "Error unserializing GRT data data string too long".

Closing the open 'local Instance' database tab allows you to open the model as normal.

I know it's the same advice as others, just logging a comment for posterity sake that it's 5 years on and still a problem.